# Fail to connect to Jabber with external IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, jabber, xmpp

I set up my own encrypted Jabber chat. I use prosody for this. When I use `localhost` or the internal IP address, I get connected without problems. But whenever I use my dynamic but up-to-date, external IP address, I get a network error in Empathy. I tried disabling Firewall in the router, but fixes nothing.

What can be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Likely candidates:

1. You have a firewall on your network which is preventing external access to the port on which Jabber is running. You must open up a hole on that port (usually done via an exclusion or port forwarding) in order to externally access the service.
2. Your ISP blocks this port. The only practical workaround in this case is to try using a different port for your Jabber server. Alternately, if you have a firewall in place as in #1, you could leverage port-forwarding to map the external port to a different numbered internal port (i.e. 52220 -> 5222). The advantage here is that you would not need to change the port that Jabber listens on and only what you use to connect to it from the outside.

Comment: I use Linux Mint 16, so no built-in firewall, and the router one disabled. Can I check which ports are being blocked by ISP?

Comment: From the outside, you can try to make a raw connection to the port to see if it is being filtered/blocked: `telnet x.x.x.x 5222`.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6848239/
My router is a DLink DSL-G624T